# Oracle 07 DICTIONARY ACCESSIBILITY

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

I just came across 07_DICTIONARY ACCESSIBILITY in oracle. I want to see, what difference it makes to data dictionary once its default value is changed to true. 
I am unable to find a suitable help on this topic on web. How am i going to implement this accessibilty in oracle 11G release 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you couldn't find it because you were looking for "zero seven" rather than "oh seven"?

Anyway, from [the online documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams134.htm):

> "O7_DICTIONARY_ACCESSIBILITY controls restrictions on SYSTEM
>   privileges. If the parameter is set to true, access to objects in the
>   SYS schema is allowed (Oracle7 behavior). The default setting of false
>   ensures that system privileges that allow access to objects in "any
>   schema" do not allow access to objects in the SYS schema."

In other words, if a user is granted SELECT ANY TABLE, this parameter regulates whether they gain access objects in the SYS schema, such as the X$ tables and the data dictionary views.  There are additional roles to explicitly grant this access if it is required.

The reason why the default is set to FALSE is that the Oracle 7 behaviour is very insecure, especially with powerful privileges like EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE.